# Overloading [] operator in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload the `[]` operator in python?

I want to access a method of a class by calling `classname[elementname]` (like in a dict).
This might seem unneccessary but the class encapsulates a database element with children that also have children that also have children that... You get the point.

If I know which child from the 3rd inheritance step I want to get I could then instead of:

```
classnname.getChild(childname1).getChild(childname2).getChild(childname3)
```

use the shorter and cleaner:

```
classnname[childname1][childname2][childname3]
```

Comment: [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)

Comment: @kindall: Thanks that totally works! Why was I not able to find this with a google/stackoverflow search?

Comment: Don't know; what were you searching for? The first Google result for `Python operator overload` has the information you seek.

Comment: That first hit I did find and read and there was no `__getitem__` in that site... Maybe I was looking for the wrong things. Thanks again for your quick help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to implement the magic method `__getitem__` on `classname`

```
class classname:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.getChild(key)
```

See [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)